# Flutter: How to convert Future<dynamic> to Map

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I need to use Map for my app. Content of this map located in Cloud. I have method to get specific nodes from FireStore and store it in Map, after that i need to use this map as `Map<DateTime,dynamic>` in the `kEvents` as show in the code. How can i do it?

Full code:

```
class Event {
  final String title;

  const Event(this.title);

  @override
  String toString() => title;
}

Map<DateTime, dynamic> testMap = {};

Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>> getEventsList() async {
  var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').get();

  for (int i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
    var time = (data.docs[i]['date'] as Timestamp).toDate();
    var title = Event(data.docs[i]['title']);
    testMap[time] = title;
  }

  print(testMap);

  return testMap;
}

Map<DateTime, dynamic> eventMap = getEventsList();

final kEvents = LinkedHashMap(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(eventMap); // Use Map here

int getHashCode(DateTime key) {
  return key.day * 1000000 + key.month * 10000 + key.year;
}

final kToday = DateTime.now();
final kFirstDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month - 1, kToday.day);
final kLastDay = DateTime(kToday.year, kToday.month + 1, kToday.day);
```

Comment: put `await` infront of the `getEventsList()`. you are using a future function.

Comment: if some method is `async` it always returns a `Future`, so your `getEventsList` should be declared as: `Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>> getEventsList() async { ...`

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your function as:

```
Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>> getEventsList() async {// your code}
```

and use as:

```
Map<DateTime, dynamic> eventMap = await getEventsList();
```

Comment: I'm having error in return `testMap;`, error is: `A value of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' can't be returned from the function 'getEventsList' because it has a return type of 'Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>>'`. How can i fix it?

Comment: @IBlackVikingl it means that you have to `return` a variable of type `Map<DateTime, dynamic>`, not `Map<dynamic, dynamic>`

Comment: where is your testMap declared?

Comment: Right above the function like this `Map testMap = {}; `

Comment: make it `Map<DateTime, dynamic> testMap = {};`

Comment: declare it as Map<DateTime, dynamic> testMap = {};

Comment: @pskink That fixed error in function. Now i'm having error in your second code, where i put await before function call `The await expression can only be used in an async function.
Try marking the function body with either 'async' or 'async*'`

Comment: so it is self explaining: try marking the function body with either `async` or `async*`

Comment: @TechnicalWorld it was there to begin with.

Comment: @pskink i'm using eventMap outside functions

Comment: Yes, its declared below the function and used in other function

Comment: I want to use result of `getEventsList` in `kEvents` in `..addAll()` part as `Map<DateTime, dynamic>`

Comment: You can convert <DateTime, dynamic> to <dynamic, dynamic> and cast it as DateTime where you want to use

Comment: How can i do it?

Comment: declare `eventMap` as `Map<dynamic, dynamic> eventMap = getEventsList();` also declare `testMap` as `Map<dynamic, dynamic> testMap = {};` and also the functions as `Future<Map<dynamic, dynamic>> getEventsList() async {// your code} `

Comment: `getEventsList().then((map) { kEvents.addAll(map); });` or simply `getEventsList().then(kEvents.addAll);`

Comment: run it on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/: `void main() {
final Map<int, int> map = {9: 99};
print('start, map: $map');
aaaa().then(map.addAll).then((_) => print('map: $map'));
}

Future<Map<int, int>> aaaa() async {
await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));
return {1: 11, 2: 22};
}` and you will see how `Future`s work