# Flutter: Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>> can't be assigned to Map<DateTime, dynamic>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that gets data from Firestore and adds it to a Map. And when i try to use it i got this error `The argument type 'Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Map<DateTime, dynamic>'.`

The code:

```
final Map<DateTime, dynamic> testMap = {};

Future<Map<DateTime, dynamic>> getEventsList() async {
  var data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('events').get();

  for (int i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
    var time = (data.docs[i]['date'] as Timestamp).toDate();
    var title = Event(data.docs[i]['title']);
    testMap[time] = title;
  }

  print(testMap);
  return testMap;
}

final kEvents = LinkedHashMap(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(getEventsList()); <-- Error is here
```

Comment: i already gave you a short code here that updates some map using `Future.then` method: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68736615/flutter-how-to-convert-futuredynamic-to-map#comment121478277_68736667, whats unclear in it? did you try to run it?

Comment: I did run it and it worked. `.then` part do not work with my code

Answer (score 1):

You need to `await` it:

```dart
final kEvents = LinkedHashMap(
  equals: isSameDay,
  hashCode: getHashCode,
)..addAll(await getEventsList());
```

However, you need to be in an [asynchronous context](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await#working-with-futures-async-and-await), such as

```dart
void _addToMap() async {
  final kEvents = LinkedHashMap(
    equals: isSameDay,
    hashCode: getHashCode,
  )..addAll(await getEventsList());
}
```

Comment: I need to use kEvents in other file: `List<Event> _getEventsForDay(DateTime day) { return kEvents[day] ?? [];}`. So i removed void and added `return kEvents`. After than in `_getEventsForDay` replaced with `addToMap()` and got this error `NoSuchMethodError: Class Future<dynamic> has no instance method '[]'`

Comment: The solution for this problem depends a lot on your code: futures generally get resolved in FutureBuilders or onTap/onPressed callbacks. Can you show where are you using `_getEventsForDay`?

Comment: I have my full [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68570081/flutter-tablecalendar-how-to-display-events-from-firebase-firestore) in this question. I'm trying to use Table Calendar to display events from Firestore.